# Unexpected use of 'open' no-restricted-globals on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a Modal dependency called 'react-responsive-modal'. It was working perfect but suddenly it stopped and there appeared an error message:

> Unexpected use of 'open'  no-restricted-globals

This error message is referencing this code line:

```
<Modal open={open}  onClose={this.onCloseModal} onExited={this.onExited} top>
```

Does anybody know how to solve it? Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'  
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';

class Interiores extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {        
      open: false
    }
  }

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });     
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };  
    
  render () {
    return (
      <div>             
        <button onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>
         
        <Modal open={open}  onClose={this.onCloseModal} onExited={this.onExited} top>
          <div>
            <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
            <p>Text here</p>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: exact but i don't know how to solve it

Comment: it was probably being used destructured from state. in `render() { const { open } = this.state; return ( ... ); }`

Comment: `this.state.open`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `open` is a reserved keyword in js .

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

I reckon you will be better off destructuring your state in your render method like

`const {open} = this.state`

But given the *intention* of the variable, IMHO it would be better to name is as `isOpen:false` .

Or change the render method as

```
      <Modal 
        open={this.state.open}
        onClose={this.onCloseModal}
        onExited={this.onExited}
        top
      >
        <div>
          <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
          <p>Text here</p>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```